# Updating plot of large arrays pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqtgraph

So using a raspberry pi, I am trying to scan a range of frequencies using an rtl-scanner and then plot that information. However, the updating plot that I get runs fairly slow. Is there anyway that I can speed this process up? Here is my code:

```
#!bin/usr/python

#gathers from the rtl library needed for this program
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
import math
from pylab import *
import time
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np


sdr = RtlSdr()

freq = 5.5e6
num_samples = 1024
##freq_range_lo = 52e6
freq_range_lo = 5.3e6
freq_range_hi = 1766e6
##freq_range_hi = 5.8e6
freq_step = 1e6

sdr.sample_rate = 1e6 
sdr.center_freq = freq
sdr.freq_correction =1142
sdr.gain = 49.6
samples = np.array([])
freq_array = []


fft_data = []
app = QtGui.QApplication([])


win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)



win.nextRow()
p6 = win.addPlot(title="Freq plot")
curve = p6.plot(pen='y')
#data = np.random.normal(size=(5.5,1766))
data = np.random.normal(size=(10,1000))
ptr = 0

def scan(low, hi, freq, freq_step):
    global samples, fft_data

    for freq in range (int(low), int(hi), int(freq_step)):
        samp_val = 0
        samples = fft(sdr.read_samples(256))
        samples = abs(samples[0::])
        for i in samples:
            samp_val += samples[i]

        fft_data.append(samp_val)


    return fft_data

def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p6,samples, fft_data
    curve.setData(scan(freq_range_lo, freq_range_hi, freq, freq_step))

    if ptr == 0:
        p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)  
    ptr += 1
    del fft_data[:]

timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(2)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

For the scanner, I am using the setup provided from this link, https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr

Any and all help in getting this sped up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your code is working, I think you should ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). See this [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: The answer depends on which part is slow.  Is it the data collection, the fft scan analysis, or the plotting.  So, step 1  is to figure that out.  Once you figure that out, I can try to help with that.

Comment: Everything really haha. However, it takes the longest time when it is scanning which leads me to believe that analysis and data collection are what's slow.